# How to set a delay in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func create()
        {
            self.Instance!.viewController!.loadCategory(category: 0)

            /*
            repeat
            {
                print("Loading category section!")
            }
            while (self.Instance!.viewController!.isLoading!)
            */
        }
```

The above code shows that I can have a delay set until isLoading is false; however, it never becomes false because it locks the thread.

How can I have this in the background?

Thanks

LoadCategory is using wkwebview to load a website's category page and sets isLoading to true when loading the content of the webpage and sets it to false when it is all done loading

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        print("Finished navigating to url \(String(describing: webView.url))")

        self.isLoading = false
    }
```

This is my function which sets it to self.isLoading to false after finished loading content.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more detail about what "loadCategory" is doing.

Comment: @ScottThompson, did it

Comment: Do not use loops or delays or any other form of polling. Use events, notifications, or observers.

Comment: Simplest solution: Replace `self.isLoading = false` in the delegate method with the code which is supposed to run after the `repeat - while` loop

Comment: You just deleted your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733884/node-js-get-response-returns-null-array that I was actively helping you on.  That's kind of rude to do without at least explaining what happened.  It's like we were in the middle of a conversation where I was helping you and you just turned and walked away without saying anything.  In person, people would think that was not cool - same here.  It would make sense to at least leave a comment about what you found.  Then, if you really want to delete the question, you can delete it after you've given me some time to see.

Comment: @jfriend00, sorry, for some reason the cookie isnt generating on heroku side, works in npm start but on heroku server cookie isnt generating

Comment: I was about to tell you that if `let text = document.cookie.split('; ').filter(cookie => cookie.includes('_abck')).pop();` generates `null`, then you still push `null` into the array.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you, idk why heroku is being so hard on me lel

Answer (score 1):

### Grand Central Dispath

In Swift you can execute a closure after a given delay using **Grand Central Dispatch**

Here's the code

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { 
    print("This will be executed 2 seconds in the future")
}
```

> Don't forget to `import Foundation`

Comment: I understand this, but what if I don't know the delay time rather only when the flag isLoading is set to false

Comment: @sdf Use the `navigationDelegate` property of `WKWebView` get notified when the navigation completes.

Answer (score 1):

A `WKWebView` can have a navigation delegate (`WKNavigationDelegate`).  That delegate can implement a method called `webView:didFinishNavigation` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview) which will tell you when the web view is finished loading content.

Based on your code, your viewController can probably be set up as the delegate for the web view and can perform whatever actions you would like after the content is loaded.

Comment: How can I have a delay with the boolean flag isLoading on a grand central dispatch